# WooCommerce My Account custom tab: "link expired" on form submission

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've added a new tab to the WooCommerce "My Account" page, so that users can manage the newsletters they're subscribed to.
The form works very well on a regular WordPress page, but once I implement it to the "My Account" page, I get an error: "The link you followed has expired". I don't get any further errors, not even in the WordPress log file.

```php
/// add menu link
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_newsletter_link', 40 );
function my_newsletter_link( $menu_links ){
    
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 5, true ) 
    + array( 'newsletter-verwaltung' => 'Newsletter' )
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true );
    
    return $menu_links;

}

// register permalink endpoint
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_endpoint' );
function my_add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'newsletter-verwaltung', EP_ROOT );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// content for the new page in My Account, woocommerce_account_{ENDPOINT NAME}_endpoint
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_newsletter-verwaltung_endpoint', 'my_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function my_my_account_endpoint_content() {

    // content
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['updateChkBox'] ) && $_POST['updateChkBox'] != '' ) {
        $newchoices = array();
        
        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $key == 'updateChkBox' ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $newchoices[] = $key;
            }
        }
        
        update_field( 'user_newsletter_segments', $newchoices, 'user_' . $user_id );
    }
    
    $fields = get_field_object( 'user_newsletter_segments', 'user_' . $user_id );
    $newsletters = get_field( 'user_newsletter_segments', 'user_' . $user_id );
    
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    
    foreach ( $fields['choices'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_array( $newsletters ) ) {
            if ( in_array( $key, array_values( $newsletters ) ) ) {
                echo '<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $key . '"> &nbsp;' . $value . '<br>';
            } else {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $key . '"> &nbsp;' . $value . '<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $key . '"> &nbsp;' . $value . '<br>';
        }
    }
    
    echo '<br><input type="submit" name="updateChkBox" value="Save"></form><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>';
}
```

I can't see why this form doesn't work on the "My Account" page.

I already tested nonces, but that didn't work either.